# How to pass two variables from two ID on click event

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have to button for click on ID that each ID id get values from database to show and hide it by i using fadeIn and fadeOut.When I click on button HIDE, I want it hide and show the button SHOW , Than I click button SHOW it's hide and show button HIDE back.

This is my HTML code:

```
 <tr>
    <td><button value ="HIDE" onclick="morefild(this);" id="show-more<?php echo $row_com_info['com_tin'];?>" /><button value ="SHOW" id ="hid-detail<?php echo $row_com_info['com_tin'];?>" style="display:none" onclick="hidefild(this);" />
    </td>
 </tr>
```

This is my JS:

```
  function morefild(item){
      var ids = $(item).attr("id");
      $('#'+ids).fadeOut();
      $('#hid-detail100077188').fadeIn();
  }
  function hidefild(idhid){
      var idhid = $(idhid).attr("id");
      $('#'+idhid).fadeOut();
      $('#show-more100077188').fadeIn();
 }
```

*Note: My code can run for static value i pass to it but i want it work all each row.

Please help me to correct it, Any command if you don't understand what i mean, thanks !!

Comment: You posted the [same/similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25173348/pass-two-pass-from-two-id-on-a-click) an hour ago <=(viewable by `10k+` members only); why did you delete it? Not because of nobody giving you a "fast" answer I hope.

Comment: Yes, i am delete it because may be everyone no understanding about what i mean.

Comment: Do not use inline event handlers...

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, it looks like you have multiple rows with the same format and you want to hide a button when it is clicked and show the sibling button.

To just fix your code, you can do something like below, here we are hiding the clicked button and then shows the next/previous button based on which one is clicked

```
function morefild(item) {
    //hide item and show the next button
    $(item).fadeOut().next().fadeIn();
}

function hidefild(idhid) {
    //hide idhid and show previous button
    $(idhid).fadeOut().prev().fadeIn();
}
```

A more jQueryish solution will be without using inline event handlers... also instead of having 2 buttons you can update a single button based on the desired state...

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/1q1gebru/)

Comment: @epascarello yes :( ... fixed

Comment: @ArunPJohny Your answer it's well but what i ask is just simple example but real I am not have only 2 button. So it's has any more solution ?